# What is the meaning of the following operation in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, machine-learning, matrix-multiplication

I'm digging out a piece of numpy code and there's a line I don't understand at all:

```
W[:, :, None] * h[None, :, :] * diff[:, None, :]
```

where **W**, **h** and **diff** are 784x20, 20x100 and 784x100 matrices. Multiplication result is 784x20x100 array, but I have no idea what does this computation actually do and what is the meaning of the result.

For what it's worth, the line is from machine learning related code, **W** corresponds to the weights array of of neural network's layer, **h** is layer activation, and **diff** is the difference between network's target and hypothesis (from  [Sida Wang's thesis](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~sidaw/home/_media/papers:thesis.pdf) on transforming autoencoder).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For NumPy arrays, `*` corresponds to element-wise multiplication. In order for this to work, the two arrays have to be either:

- the same shape as each other
- such that one array can be [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to the other

One array can be broadcast to another if, when pairing the trailing dimensions of each array, either the lengths in each pair are equal or one of the lengths is 1.

For example, the following arrays `A` and `B` have shapes which are compatible for broadcasting:

```
A.shape == (20, 1, 3)
B.shape ==     (4, 3)
```

(`3` is equal to `3` and then the next length in `A` is `1` which can be paired with any length. It doesn't matter that `B` has fewer dimensions than `A`.)

To make two incompatible arrays broadcastable with each other, extra dimensions can be inserted into one or both arrays. Indexing a dimension with `None` or `np.newaxis` inserts an extra dimension of length one into an array.

---

Let's look at the example in the question. Python evaluates repeated multiplications left to right:

- `W[:, :, None]` has shape `(784,  20,   1)`
- `h[None, :, :]` has shape `(  1,  20, 100)`

These shapes are broadcastable according to the explanation above and the multiplication returns an array with shape `(784, 20, 100)`.

- Array shape from last multiplication,   `(784, 20, 100)`
- `diff[:, None, :]` has a shape of `(784,  1, 100)`

These shapes of these two arrays are compatible so the second multiplication succeeds. An array with the shape `(784, 20, 100)` is returned.